# Matlab how to change file names from 1_x_10_a.jpg to 01_x_010_a.jpg

Tags: matlab, file-rename

I have really a lot of files named like:

```
1_x_0_a.jpg, 1_x_0_b.jpg, 1_x_5_a.jpg ... 15_x_160_a.jpg, 15_x_160_b.jpg, 15_x_165_a.jpg
```

I would like to change the file names as follows:

```
01_x_000_a.jpg, 01_x_000_b.jpg, 01_x_005_a.jpg
```

So, before x should be a number with 2 dig and after x with 3 digits.

Comment: @erik: I undid your edit. I agree that this is a file-rename question that can be handled on the system level, but the OP specifically wants to know how to perform this operation in Matlab.

Comment: @Jonas Ok, then it should get both tags. Because it is a file-rename problem. I didn‘t know that matlab is able to change filenames. Please readd the file-rename tag, so that other can learn that you can use matlab to manage your filenames. :-)

Comment: @erik: fair enough. Done.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work on relatively newer versions of MATLAB.

```
fileStruct = dir;
files = {fileStruct.name};
for oldFile = files
    oldFile = oldFile{1};  //Takes string out of cell

    // Embedding the sprintf in a regexprep only works in certain versions
    newFile = regexprep(oldFile, '^(\d*)', '${sprintf(''%02d'', str2num($1))}');
    newFile = regexprep(newFile, '(?<=_)(\d*)(?=_)', '${sprintf(''%03d'', str2num($1))}');

    movefile(oldFile, newFile);
end
```

Comment: Hmm, now what it does, it adds one digit in the first number but in some occasion it doesn't change the 2nd number. For example: 7_x_30_a.jpg .....Here it never adds 030

Does somebody knows why? Thanks

Comment: I need always just 2 digits before x and 3digits after: dd_x_ddd

Comment: @MareB Ah sorry, added the missing asterisks. Should work now

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps that should help you:

1. Use `dir` to get a list of file names.
2. Use `regexprep` to replace starting numbers by starting numbers with leading zeros
3. Use `regexprep` to replace middle numbers by starting numbers with up to two zeros
4. Use `rename` to change the file names

Note that I have not tried it and the documentation of rename is a bit strange as it refers to ftp sites, but it might just work. If it does not work, I guess you can just copy all the files and then remove the old ones.

Comment: Excellent answer! This is the process I use except, I use the `movefile` command rather than `rename`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix or Linux machine you can try this small **shell script**:

In a terminal go to the directory where you have your files.

You can first try it without really renaming your files, by replacing the `mv` with `echo` to see if it works as expected.

```
for file in *; do
  mv $file $(echo $file | awk -F '_' '{ printf "%02d_%s_%003d_%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }')
done
```

or as a one liner

```
for file in *; do mv $file $(echo $file | awk -F '_' '{ printf "%02d_%s_%003d_%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }'); done
```

For files

```
1_x_0_a.jpg
1_x_0_b.jpg
1_x_5_a.jpg
15_x_160_a.jpg
15_x_160_b.jpg
15_x_165_a.jpg
```

I get the result

```
01_x_000_a.jpg
01_x_000_b.jpg
01_x_005_a.jpg
15_x_160_a.jpg
15_x_160_b.jpg
15_x_165_a.jpg
```

Comment: Is this regular matlab? If not how to run it?

Comment: No, sorry. This not Matlab syntax but Shell Script. Just another way to accomplish the task in a Unix/Linux Shell. It is less to write. :-)